# How to prevent inclusion of C library destructors and atexit()?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, embedded, bare-metal

Using [arm-none-eabi-gcc](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded) for Cortex-M4 (baremetal application), the code for `malloc` is also emitted even though I never use `malloc` in my code.

Seeing the assembly output with `arm-none-eabi-objdump -xS obj.elf`, it seems that `malloc` is called by `__register_exitproc` called by `atexit` called by `register_fini`

```asm
004036a8 <register_fini>:
  4036a8:       4b02            ldr     r3, [pc, #8]    ; (4036b4 <register_fini+0xc>)
  4036aa:       b113            cbz     r3, 4036b2 <register_fini+0xa>
  4036ac:       4802            ldr     r0, [pc, #8]    ; (4036b8 <register_fini+0x10>)
  4036ae:       f000 b805       b.w     4036bc <atexit>
  4036b2:       4770            bx      lr
  4036b4:       00000000        .word   0x00000000
  4036b8:       004036c9        .word   0x004036c9
```

However, `register_fini` is never called in the code. `main()` is called using the following startup code, so even if main exits, the destructors (or functions registered with `atexit()`) will not get called.

```
/**
 * \brief This is the code that gets called on processor reset.
 * To initialize the device, and call the main() routine.
 */
void Reset_Handler(void)
{
    uint32_t *pSrc, *pDest;

    /* Initialize the relocate segment */
    pSrc = &_etext;
    pDest = &_srelocate;

    if (pSrc > pDest) {
        for (; pDest < &_erelocate;) {
            *pDest++ = *pSrc++;
        }
    } else if (pSrc < pDest) {
        uint32_t nb_bytes = (uint32_t)&_erelocate - (uint32_t)&_srelocate;
        pSrc = (uint32_t*)((uint32_t)pSrc + nb_bytes) - 1;
        pDest = (uint32_t*)((uint32_t)pDest + nb_bytes) - 1;
        for (;nb_bytes;nb_bytes -= 4) {
            *pDest-- = *pSrc--;
        }
    }
    __NOP();

    /* Clear the zero segment */
    for (pDest = &_szero; pDest < &_ezero;) {
        *pDest++ = 0;
    }

    /* Set the vector table base address */
    pSrc = (uint32_t *) & _sfixed;
    SCB->VTOR = ((uint32_t) pSrc);

    /* Initialize the C library */
    __libc_init_array();

    /* Branch to main function */
    main();

    /* Infinite loop */
    while (1);
}
```

The code is compiled with `-ffunction-sections` and `-fdata-sections` and linked with the flag `--gc-sections` so that any unreachable code/functions are not included in the output file.

---

So, how can I prevent these functions (`register_fini`, `atexit`, `malloc`, etc) that are never used in my code from being included in the object file?

---

Compile options

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -o build/main.o -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -pipe -g3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-expansion-to-defined -Werror -std=gnu11 -fno-strict-aliasing -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -DARM_MATH_CM4=true -D__SAM4SD32C__ -Ibunch -Iof -Iinclude -Idirs src/main.c
```

Link options

```
arm-none-eabi-g++ -o build/tnc.elf -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -pipe -Wl,--entry=Reset_Handler -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--script my/linker/script.ld build/src/bunch.o build/src/of.o build/src/object.o build/src/files.o build/src/main.o -lm
```

Comment: Do any functions that you use implicitly call `atexit()`?  Use of functions such as `fopen()` or `printf()` can cause exit handlers to be installed for streams so they get flushed on exit.

Comment: Do you compile your own "newlib" C library? If so, you can use the `--disable-newlib-atexit-dynamic-alloc` ./configure option when you build it to prevent `atexit` using `malloc`.

Comment: List all the options you use with `gcc`, so we have a better idea of what you are actually doing. (`-ffreestanding`? `-nodefaultlibs`? `-nostdlib`?)

Comment: @NominalAnimal Added to the question. I need some functions from the stdib (`memcpy`, `memset`, math functions, etc)

Comment: @IanAbbott No, I didn't compile libc myself. It seems that `/usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m/libc.a` is used. (installed when using the gcc-arm-embedded ppa). (not sure if this is newlib)

Comment: @AndrewHenle Not in a way that might show  up in static analysis. Neither `register_fini` nor `atexit` are called from anywhare directly in the disassembled final linked elf file. (I don't know if they could be called using function pointers at runtime).

Comment: GCC provides [built-in functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins) for those. Are there any you need that are not available as GCC built-ins?

Comment: Why are you linking with G++ do call the C++ machinery like `register_fini`?  Do you have C++?  Do you have static objects?

Comment: @artlessnoise https://answers.launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+question/253559 ; In short, the compiler will call the linker with necessary options as this is a multilib toolchain. The results are the same even if `arm-none-eabi-gcc` is used for linking instead of `arm-none-eabi-g++`. I do not use C++, though I do use static objects. `.bss` is initialized to zero in the `Reset_Handler()` snippet in the question.

Answer (score 5):

Probably you need `-fno-use-cxa-atexit` argument for compiler.

Look on this simple example to get working C++ code on pure bare-metal: https://github.com/cortexm/baremetal

Answer (score 3):

So here's the workaround that I'm using. Not perfect, but good enough.

Using the [`--wrap`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options) option of `ld`, I can provide my own definition for `atexit` that doesn't do anything.

```
int __wrap_atexit(void __attribute__((unused)) (*function)(void)) {
    return -1;
}
```

and then link with `--wrap=atexit` option.

Now, `atexit` does not call any other functions and the `-ffunction-sections` and `--gc-sections` options ensure that `malloc` is not included in the output file.

---

Additionally, to enforce that `malloc` isn't included, a `--wrap=malloc` option can be passed while linking *without* defining `__wrap_malloc` anywhere. This will fail with a link error if some other function happens to use `malloc`.

Answer (score 3):

In an environment with limited memory such as the Cortex M4, another option is to use newlib-nano. It provides a `__register_exitproc()` that is weakly linked. Therefore it is easy to override with your own empty function that avoids calling `malloc()`. This will have the additional benefit of removing `__call_exitprocs()` from your binary as well.

- Add the flag `--specs=nano.specs` to your compiler and linker options.
- Create the following function somewhere in your compiled code:
  `void __register_exitproc(void) { }`

Note that this will prevent destructors being called for static instances of classes. This seems appropriate in your example.

See the comments in the [newlib source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/native_client/nacl-newlib/+/master/newlib/libc/stdlib/__atexit.c) for more details.

Comment: This actually worked, even without __register_exitproc! Though I had to use a single dash for the -specs option.

Answer (score 0):

`-nostartfiles` and `-nostdlib` worked for me in a similar context.